# Printing a variable number of arguments to a format string

Tags: c, formatting, printf, variadic-functions

Given a format string, a counter variable for the number of specifiers and an array of the strings to be inputted, how could this be printed?

Here's an example:

```
char *format_str = "str(%s)ing(%s)";
int count = 2;
char **specs = { [0] = "rts", [1] = "gni" };
```

So, the list of strings aligns respectively with the ordering of specifiers. When printed, the end result would be:

```
"str(rts)ing(gni)"
```

Could a function be written to print such a string with any format string & any number of specifiers & respective arguments? I have tried to do this using `strtok()`, `vsprintf`, `snprintf` etc, but I still cannot get it quite right.

EDIT: To clarify, `format_str` contains `count` number of specifiers and the array `specs` contains `count` number of strings. The proposed function would therefore should print `count` number of strings into `format_str`.

Comment: `with any format string & any number of specifiers & respective arguments?` I do not understand. What does it mean "any"? No, `%s` expects a `char *`, it can't take another type. Could you provide more examples? Could you provide what have you tried? Even if it failed it will help as a boilerplate code for others. Could you provide a function declaration of how would you see the interface? What should the input be?  `how could this be printed?` is `printf(format_str, specs[0], specs[1])` not enough?

Comment: Is the string reversing part of the question or just an example?

Comment: Is the number of `%s` in the format string alway equal to `count`

Comment: @KamilCuk In the sense that the proposed function works algorithmically with a variable number of specifiers. So, the format string could be "text(%s)string(%s)word(%s)" where count = 3 and there are 3 strings in the array.    printf(format_str, specs[0], specs[1]) is not enough because that only works with two specifiers. I want a function that'll be called as     func(format_str, count, specs) and it will print the given string based on the arguments passed (count could be any integer, format_str contains <count> number of specifiers and specs contains <count> number of strings.)

Comment: @4386427 Yes. That's the point. format_str contains <count> number of specifiers and **specs contains <count> number of strings. The function would therefore print <count> number of strings to format_str.

Comment: @4386427 String reversing is not part of the question.

Comment: So besides the `count` `%s` specificers the format string may contain some text between the `%s` specifiers - correct?

Comment: @4386427 Yes. The format_str contains specifiers and text (in any order). The count variable simply reflects how many specifiers & input strings there are.

Comment: So the `count` information is redundant - the count of elements is already available via parsing the formatting string? Honestly, this looks like XY problem.

Comment: [This is another example of run-time - using user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920616/decimals-digits-in-c-language) to modify format specifier of a format string

Comment: `char **specs = { [0] = "rts", [1] = "gni" };` not valid C.  "and the array specs contains count number of strings." --> `specs` is not an array either.  Post needs repair.

Comment: Gabriel Saul, what is the max value of `count`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wasn't intended to be valid C code, only to show the nature of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said there is no direct way of doing that. You can build your own function which dumps the values of strings at the correct format specifiers. Below function makes a temporary format string for each `%s` and appends it to the earlier build string using `snprintf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF      4096

char *strmaker(char* format, int num_args, char** strings)
{
    char* prnt = calloc(sizeof(char), MAXBUF);
    int prnt_ct = 0;
    char* tmp_fmt = malloc(strlen(format) + 1); // Prepare for the worst case (format == tmp_fmt).
    int fmt_ct = 0;

    /* Append the strings to the prnt buffer */

    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; i++) {
        char* s_loc = strstr(format + fmt_ct, "%s");    // Search the format-string for string specifier (%s)
        if (s_loc == NULL)
            return prnt;

        int tmp_fmt_len = (int) (s_loc + 2 - format - fmt_ct);  // +2 for %s
        strncpy(tmp_fmt, format + fmt_ct, tmp_fmt_len); // Make tmp_fmt
        tmp_fmt[tmp_fmt_len] = '\0';
        fmt_ct = fmt_ct + tmp_fmt_len;

        int p_return = snprintf(prnt + prnt_ct, MAXBUF - prnt_ct, tmp_fmt, strings[i]);   // If no error, return the number characters printed excluding nul (man page)

        if (p_return >= MAXBUF - prnt_ct)   // If buffer overflows (man page)
            return prnt;

        prnt_ct = prnt_ct + p_return;   // Update the index location.
    }

    return prnt;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Pass format and arguments
{
    if (argc <= 1)
       return -1;

    char *s = strmaker(argv[1], argc - 2, argv + 2);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Terminal Session:**

```
$ ./a.out '%s %s %s' 1 2 3 
1 2 3
$ ./a.out 'one %s two %s three %s' 1 2 3 
one 1 two 2 three 3
$ ./a.out 'one %s two %s three' 1 2 3 
one 1 two 2
$ ./a.out 'one %s two %s three %s' 1 2 
one 1 two 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to give a different number of arguments to `printf` at runtime.

Therefore you'll have to build the output string yourself.

I'll not dump all the code but only give you some ideas at high level.

```
#define OUT_STR_SIZE 8192

char* outStr = calloc(OUT_STR_SIZE, 1);   // Allocate an output buffer
assert(outStr  != NULL);
char* tmp = format_str;  // tmp pointer to track how much of the format string
                         // that has been handled
size_t idx = 0;          // next position in output buffer to write
size_t str_idx = 0;      // index of next string to copy when %s is found

while(*tmp)  // Loop the whole format string
{
    if (*tmp = '%' && *(tmp+1) == 's')
    {
        // Copy a string to output buffer
        strcpy(&outStr[idx], specs[str_idx]);  // Append a string from specs
        idx = idx + strlen(str_idx);
        ++str_idx;
        tmp += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        // Copy a single char to output buffer
        outStr[idx] = *tmp;
        ++idx;
        ++tmp;
    }
}
assert(count == str_idx);  // Just checking that all %s was handled

printf("%s", outStr);

free(outStr);
```

**Bad things with the code that need to be fixed**

The output string size is fixed at 8192 chars. If that's not always enough, you need to check the available space as you add new chars and use `realloc` when you run out of space.

The code will fail for format strings like "hello\%s%s" due to the '\'

I'll leave it as an exercise for OP to fix these things.

Comment: `strcat(outStr, ...)` is a terrible idea as it would make the cost of such a simple function quadratic in the length of the final string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are lazy, you can do:

```
int func(const char *fmt, int count, const char **specs) {
    switch(count) {
    case 1: return printf(fmt, specs[0]);
    case 2: return printf(fmt, specs[0], specs[1]);
    case 3: return printf(fmt, specs[0], specs[1], specs[2]);
    // etc. for as many args you want to support
    }
}
```

If you are not lazy, you should parse `%s` formatting string on your own (for example as in the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

The C standard library does not provide functions similar to `printf` that work on a variable number of arguments provided as an array. In order to do what you want, you would have to roll your own.

If you want to dynamically construct such a string, a good old `for(...) realloc()` loop is the way to go. Here's a simple implementation (it could probably be optimized more).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *my_sprintf(const char *fmt, size_t n, char *const *strings) {
    const char *fmt_start, *fmt_end;
    size_t i, len, prev_len, fmt_len, spec_len;
    char *res, *tmp;

    fmt_start = fmt;
    len = 0;
    res = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // Find position of next %s format specifier.
        fmt_end = strstr(fmt_start, "%s");
        if (fmt_end == NULL) {
            // Error out if not found.
            free(res);
            return NULL;
        }
        
        // Do some math...
        fmt_len = fmt_end - fmt_start; // Length of current format specifier segment.
        spec_len = strlen(strings[i]); // Length of current string.
        prev_len = len;            // Previous total length.
        len += fmt_len + spec_len; // New total length.

        // Increase the size of the final string.
        tmp = realloc(res, len + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            // Error out if realloc() fails.
            free(res);
            return NULL;
        }

        res = tmp;
        
        // Copy specifier segment and i-th string at the end of the final string.
        memcpy(res + prev_len, fmt_start, fmt_len);
        memcpy(res + prev_len + fmt_len, strings[i], spec_len);
        
        // Skip current specifier.
        fmt_start = fmt_end + 2;
    }

    // Copy last specifier segment (if needed).
    
    fmt_len = strlen(fmt_start);
    prev_len = len;
    len += fmt_len;

    tmp = realloc(res, len + 1);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        free(res);
        return NULL;
    }

    res = tmp;
    memcpy(res + prev_len, fmt_start, fmt_len);
    res[len] = '\0';

    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *res = my_sprintf(argv[1], argc - 2, argv + 2);

    if (res != NULL) {
        puts(res);
        free(res);
    } else {
        puts("ERR");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I particularly like this approach because it has a few advantages:

1. No need to know the length of the resulting string upfront, final string is dynamically allocated.
2. No need to modify any of the strings provided as argument.
3. Uses `memcpy()`, iterating over the whole final string twice (one time to check length, one to copy), unlike solutions involving `strlen()` + `strcpy()`, which could potentially iterate over the result *three* times (a common implementation for `strcpy(dst, src)` is `memcpy(dst, src, strlen(src) + 1)`).
4. Simple error checking in case the number of specifiers is not enough (you can decide what to do inside those `if` statements if you don't want to just return `NULL`.